# Why does reference_wrapper<string> comparison not work?

Tags: c++, reference-wrapper

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    auto ref = std::ref(x);
    if (x < ref)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the above code, I made an `int` variable and a `reference_wrapper<int>` variable, and then compared   them, and it works well.

However, If I change the type `int` to `string`, It raises a compile error like this.

`binary '<': 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`

I thought that `reference_wrapper<string>` would be implicitly converted to `string`, but wouldn't.
Are there any rules that prevent implicit conversion from `reference_wrapper<string>` to `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::reference_wrapper<>` more or less supports only one operation: an **implicit type conversion** back to the original type (which is `std::string` in your case).

But the **problem** is that the compiler has to know that an *implicit conversion* back to the original type is **necessary**.

That is why your example works with the **built-in type** `int`, while not with the class template instantiation `std::string` of the `basic_string` class template.

The situation is similar to the below given example:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyWrapper 
{
    operator T()
    {
        return T{};
    }
};
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    MyWrapper<int> ref;
    
    if(x < ref)  //WORKS WITH INT
    {
        
    }
    
    std::string x2 = "f";
    MyWrapper<std::string> ref2;
    
    if(x2 < ref2)  //WON'T WORK WITH STD::STRING
    {
        
    }
    
}
```

To **solve** this problem, we need to explicitly say that we want the original type, which we can do by using the `get()` member function, as shown below:

```
std::string x = "hi";
auto ref = std::ref(x);
//----------vvvvv------->get() member function used here
if (x < ref.get())
{
        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is because std::string is a template instantiation of std::basic_string and therefor when it tries to call the operator it can't find an exact match. [link to std::string operator definitions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for the nice first/second contribution!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::reference_wrapper<T>::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get)
for explicit conversion.

`int` is a *primitive* data type, while `string` is a *template* type as mentioned by [Tyler Wojciechowski.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14346590/tyler-wojciechowski)

---

Illustration

```
int main()
{
    string x = "hi";
    auto ref = std::ref(x).get();
    if (x < ref)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```